# Is there any way to play .amr files in IOS swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I have some audio files which are in `amr` format, which I cant convert to any other format, Is there any way to play this files in IOS using swift`(AVFoundation)`?

I tried this code

```
var audioPlaying = AVAudioPlayer()
audioPlaying = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:
       NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("music", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
audioPlaying.play()
```

but when I use the `"amr"` in `ofType:`, getting an error which file not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The Opencore-AMR iOS framework is probably your best starting point.

[github.com/feuvan/opencore-amr-iOS](http://github.com/feuvan/opencore-amr-iOS)

Also here's a guide on how to compile it for iOS as it's not an easy task :

http://swati-ios.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/compile-opencore-amr-for-ios-projects.html

Answer (score 3):

`AMR` format is [no longer supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html) by Apple (since `iOS 4.3`).

If you want to *Play* or *Record* one, you have to use some tools (like `opencore-amr` library) [to change the format](https://github.com/justinjing/RecordWAVToAMRDemo/blob/master/AmrConvertAndRecord/VoiceConvert/VoiceConverter.mm).

Comment: Can you say how to use this? I am using swift?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution working Perfectly in Swift 4 and Xcode 9:

1-Use the following Library to Decode Amr to Wav using Carthage:
https://github.com/teambition/AMRAudioSwift

for How to install FrameWork on Xcode Using Carthage visit the following link:
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage

Import those Libraries in your Code:

```
import AMRAudioSwift
import AVFoundation
```

2-Use the following code to Play AMR File:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
func playAmr() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Your Amr File", withExtension: "amr", subdirectory:"your Amr Parent Folder") else { return }

    do {
        let audioRecorder = AMRAudioRecorder()
        audioRecorder.volume = 3
        audioRecorder.delegate = self as? AMRAudioRecorderDelegate
        let wavData = AMRAudio.decodeAMRDataToWAVEData(amrData: try!Data(contentsOf:url))
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:wavData , fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Good Luck and Happy Support for AMR files.